# why does a battle of the sexes game best response curve for two players in game theory have three points in common?

Tags: game-theory

[image]

Why does the mixed strategy best response curve shown in the image linked above have three common points and what does it signify?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_(game)

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The graph superimposes the map for the best reply of Player 1 and the map for the best reply of Player 2. Each map reports the probabilities with which Player $i$ should pick his first strategy as a function of the probability with which the opponent picks her first strategies. The three Nash equilibria for the game correspond to three intersection points: two are equilibria in pure strategies (corner points) and one is in completely mixed strategies (interior point).